# How to make TortoisGit ignore line-ending differences on the Commit, Log and Diff windows?

Tags: tortoisegit, line-endings, eol, end-of-line

TortoiseGit, supposedly, reads settings from the `.gitconfig`, `.gitignore` file(s). In our project, we regularly encounter EOL type changes due to a mix between *NIX and Windows environments, but Git settings takes care of that when committing the changes.

When I type `git diff` or `git status` on the command line, the diff tool ignores EOL changes, and files which only differ by this are not listed.

However, when viewing the file diff lists on the various TortoiseGit windows (like, on the commit window), I get those files listed, but with the "Lines added" and "Lines removed" numbers set to 0.

How can I set TortoiseGit to ignore those EOL-modified files and not show them on those lists, similar to the `git diff` behaviour?

Comment: check [core.autocrlf setting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: @magicandre1981 - thanks, but where? I don't want to mess up with the project's config files.

Comment: can [setting an be applied per system or per user](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html)